# Linux command to do wild card matching

Tags: linux, bash, shell, wildcard

Is there any bash command to do something similar to:

```
if [[ $string =~ $pattern ]]
```

but that it works with simple wild cards (?,*) and not complex regular expressions ??

---

**More info:**

I have a config file (a sort of .ini-like file) where each line is composed of a wild card pattern and some other data.
For any given input string that my script receives, I have to find the first line in the config file where the wild card pattern matches the input string and then return the rest of the data in that line.
It's simple. I just need a way to match a string against wild card patterns and not RegExps since the patterns may contain dots, brackets, dashes, etc. and I don't want those to be interpreted as special characters.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish?  more details please...

Comment: to match a string against a wild-card pattern

Comment: hrm. fair enough. if this is a "how can i do this with unix tools" question, my answer is "perl". if it's a "how can i do this with bash", i say it should be migrated to stackoverflow.com as a bash programming question.  any thoughts?

Comment: Since I was asking for a simple command I didn't think this was a "programming" question really

Comment: well, since what you're really asking about is bash syntax a.k.a. bash programming syntax, i think it's more of a programming question.  i'm voting to migrate.  it's a good question, but i think more appropriate to SO.

Comment: I would have voted to migrate it to serverfault since it's really shell programming. I guess it's really about how you see it.

Comment: shell programming is acceptable on SO, but i think it's only SF material if there's a specific admin aspect to it.  since this is a more general question i'll stick with my suggestion of SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[ -z ${string/$pattern} ]` trick has some pretty serious problems: if string is blank, it'll match all possible patterns; if it contains spaces, the test command will parse it as part of an expression (try `string="x -o 1 -eq 1"` for amusement).  bash's [[ expressions do glob-style wildcard matching natively with the == operator, so there's no need for all these elaborate (and trouble-prone) tricks.  Just use:

```
if [[ $string == $pattern ]]
```

Comment: Sure it's with two equal signs?

Comment: Yes, for `[[ $foo == $bar ]]`, `bash` matches the contents of `foo` against the pattern in `bar`. Note, that this is note the same as `[[ $foo == "$bar" ]]`, which will not treat the contents of `bar` as a pattern.

Comment: @GetFree: Two equal signs seems to be preferred, but you can use either `=` or `==` interchangeably in this particular case.

Comment: @Chris Johnsen: It's actually even cooler than that, as you can mix quoted (literal) and unquoted (pattern-matched) strings, for example `[[ $string == "$foo"$bar ]]` will require that the `$foo` portion match exactly, while the `$bar` part must match as a pattern.

Answer (score 2):

There's several ways of doing this.

In bash >= 3, you have regex matching like you describe, e.g.

```
$ foo=foobar
$ if [[ $foo =~ f.ob.r ]]; then echo "ok"; fi
   ok
```

Note that this syntax uses regex patterns, so it uses `.` instead of `?` to match a single character.

If what you want to do is just test that the string contains a substring, there's more classic ways of doing that, e.g.

```
# ${foo/b?r/} replaces "b?r" with the empty string in $foo
# So we're testing if $foo does not contain "b?r" one time
$ if [[ ${foo/b?r/} = $foo ]]; then echo "ok"; fi
```

You can also test if a string begins or ends with an expression this way:

```
# ${foo%b?r} removes "bar" in the end of $foo
# So we're testing if $foo does not end with "b?r"
$ if [[ ${foo%b?r} = $foo ]]; then echo "ok"; fi

# ${foo#b?r} removes "b?r" in the beginning of $foo
# So we're testing if $foo does not begin with "b?r"
$ if [[ ${foo#b?r} = $foo ]]; then echo "ok"; fi
     ok
```

See the **Parameter Expansion** paragraph of [man bash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) for more info on these syntaxes. Using `##` or `%%` instead of `#` and `%` respectively will achieve a longest matching instead of a simple matching.

Another very classic way of dealing with wildcards is to use case:

```
case $foo in 
   *bar)
       echo "Foo matches *bar"
       ;;
   bar?)
       echo "Foo matches bar?"
       ;;
   *)
       echo "Foo didn't match any known rule"
       ;;
esac
```

Comment: Ah, that's yet another option indeed :-)

Answer (score 0):

John T's answer was deleted, but I actually think he was on the right track.  Here it is:

> Another portable method which will work in most versions of bash is 
>   to echo your string then pipe to grep. If no match is found, it will
>   evaluate to false as the result will be blank. If something is returned,
>   it will evaluate to true.
>
> ```
> [john@awesome]$string="Hello World"
> [john@awesome]$if [[ `echo $string | grep Hello` ]];then echo "match";fi
> match
> ```

What John didn't consider is the wildcard requested by the answer.  For that, use `egrep`, a.k.a. `grep -E`, **and** use the regex wildcard `.*`.  Here, `.` is the wildcard, and `*` is a multiplier meaning "any number of these".  So, John's example becomes:

```
$ string="Hello World"
$ if [[ `echo $string | egrep "Hel.*"` ]]; then echo "match"; fi
```

The `.` wildcard notation is fairly standard regex, so it should work with any command that speaks regex's.

It does get nasty if you need to escape the special characters, so this may be sub-optimal:

```
$ if [[ `echo $string | egrep "\.\-\$.*"` ]]; then echo "match"; fi
```

Comment: Yeah, wasn't gonna bother. But thanks for resurrecting my answer I guess! :)

Comment: you deleted it as i was crafting this suggestion as a comment.... it does break down into the suggestion to "use regex wildcards", but oh well.  not a great answer, just an answer.

Comment: sure it will. `"?"` wildcard means "match one character, doesn't matter what". that's exactly what `"."` means in a regex. it's not the same character for the wildcard, but it has the same meaning.

Comment: GetFree: the '?' wildcard would be replaced by '.' just as when using '=~'.

Comment: so in regex, `"."` is the same as `"?"` wildcard; `".+"` means "match one or more any-characters"; `".*"` means "match zero or more any-characters".  `foo.` matches "foob" but not "foobar"; `foo.+` matches "foob" and "foobar" but not "foo"; and `foo.*` matches all 3.